# "Can't find export handler for war", while trying to export WSO2 web app

Tags: java, wso2

I keep getting the error below, while trying to Export Project as Deployable Archive.
Here is what I see in the log:

```
!MESSAGE An error occured while creating the archive file
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: Can't find export handler for war
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.core.project.export.util.ExportUtil.buildProject(ExportUtil.java:84)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.ui.wizard.ProjectExportWizard.exportArchivable(ProjectExportWizard.java:121)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.ui.wizard.ProjectExportWizard.performFinish(ProjectExportWizard.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.ui.action.ExportProjectAction.run(ExportProjectAction.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Somebody had this problem in the past : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469456/cannot-export-web-application-to-wso2-application-server-with-developer-studio-2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469456/cannot-export-web-application-to-wso2-application-server-with-developer-studio-2

Comment: Neither of those questions has an answer as to what was wrong, or how they fixed it... so maybe calling this a duplicate is a bit premature.

Comment: IS this the full stack trace? Or  do you have any caused by stuff that you didn't post?

Comment: Thihara - it's a full stack trace from the log. I just downloaded WSO2 Developer Studio from this location - http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/ and was able to export the project. However, I kept getting the same error with SpringSource Tool Suite and Juno-SR2 with WSO2 Dev Studio installed as a plugin...

Comment: Martin, I agree with Bailey, there is no an answer as to what was wrong and how to fix the problem. Getting WSO2 Dev Studio from WSO2 is  a workaround, but I expected the plugin to work seamlessly with STS and Juno SR2 as well. Would be great to get an answer from the WSO2 guys.

Comment: Dmitriy, can you follow the steps given below and provide the results. 1. Start your eclipse with command line with "-console" switch as a parameter e.g: eclipse.exe -console or ./eclipse -console 2. Once the eclipse started try to export the WAR and if you still get this error, type "ss org.wso2" and print the result here. This error is caused by Developer Studio WAR file exporter is not correctly registered via the extension and the reason could be bundle is not started correctly for some reason and OSGi console will help to figure out the issue.Thus please provide the requested information.

Comment: Harshana, here is the requested information:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_f0ropxRiIkQ21lV290OTViRG8&usp=sharing

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @HarshanaMartin, any luck with the console message?
Thank you.

Comment: @DmitriyMelikov i'm returning from holiday. I will have a look and provide you an update. Thanks for providing the requested information quickly!

Comment: @DmitriyMelikov I've found the root cause for this error. It seems the following property is missing in the pom.xml of the web-app project.  
  <properties>
    <CApp.type>web/application</CApp.type>
  </properties>

Once you add this property to pom.xml of your web-app,you will be able to export without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because the following property is missing in the pom.xml of your web-app project.

```
<properties>
    <CApp.type>web/application</CApp.type>
  </properties>
```

Once you add this to the Web-App project pom.xml you will be able to export the WAR file successfully.

/Harshana

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi @Harshana martin,
If i want to create JAR as deployable artifact by using wso2 mediator project, i am getting error like "java.lang.Exception: Can't find export handler for bundle" in wso2 integration studio. May i know the solution for the same?